# Adding several shapefiles to GroupLayer fast using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I want to add a bunch (several hundreds) of shapefiles (all feature layers) to a `GroupLayer`.

When I add them file by file this takes too long:

```cs
IWorkspaceFactory pWorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWorkspace = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(dir, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer();
pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(filename);
pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;
groupLayer.Add(pFeatureLayer);
```

I found [IMapLayers.InsertLayersInGroup](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000905000000) which takes an `IEnumLayer` but I can't find a way to load the shapefiles as an `IEnumLayer`. So I can't even say, if this would be faster.

Does anyone have a clue?

**Update**
I tried Kirk's hint with `IName` like this (totally ignoring possible null values):

```
IWorkspaceFactory pWorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWorkspace = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(dir, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;

IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer();
IWorkspace w = pFeatureWorkspace as IWorkspace;
var names = w.get_DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass);
names.Reset();
IDataLayer pDataLayer = pFeatureLayer as IDataLayer;
pDataLayer.DataSourceName = names.Next() as IName;                   
groupLayer.Add(pFeatureLayer);
```

It takes more than double as long as my first shot. So I think I'll stick with that one.

Comment: Did you try [implementing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) `IEnumLayer`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are being unrealistic, adding several hundred layers to a map document or even grouplayer will make the map document unwieldy and almost certainly unstable. If you think about it on each insertion it needs to place it in the TOC, symbolize the data and if left on refresh the map display.

`IEnumLayer` to my knowledge only comes from `IMap` so your layers (that's the hint) need to be already loaded. You could get a handle on a `IEnumDataSet` from `IWorkspace.Datasets` Property and add the datasets to the map that way. But adding hundreds will always be a slow process.

Consider turning off display while loading? You can use the `IMxApplication2.PauseDrawing` Property for that.

Comment: The layers are not very big. Most of them only have a couple of features. 
Unfortunatly `IMxApplication2.PauseDrawing` isn't available in ArcEngine.
I'll have a look at `IEnumDataSet`.

Comment: If speed is a priority and you really do have so few features per dataset, why not preprocess the data and merge them with a field Identifying which dataset they came from?  Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this, but it might be worth a try.

Opening featureclasses is what takes a long time.  In general, it's much faster to deal with `IName` objects instead of featureclasses.  So perhaps `IDataLayer` could be used.  Instead of setting `IFeatureLayer.Featureclass`, try setting `IDataLayer.DataSourceName` to a `FeatureClassName` cast as an `IName`.

If the featurelayer doesn't try to open it when this is set, it should be faster.

Comment: I tried it (see my update) but it is slower.